# Problem about construction of linear map using the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Map.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have some problem with the theorem:

> Linear maps can be constructed that take on arbitrary values on a basis. Specifically, given a basis $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ of $V$ and any choice of vectors $w_1, \dots, w_n \in W$, we can construct a linear map $T: V \to W$ such that $T(v_j) = w_j$ for $j = 1, \dots, n$. There is no choice of how to do this — we must define $T$ by $T(a_1v_1 + \dots + a_nv_n) = a_1w_1 + \dots + a_nw_n$, where $a_1, \dots, a_n$ are arbitrary elements of $\mathbb{F}$. Because $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, the equation above does indeed define a function $T$ from $V$ to $W$. You should verify that the function $T$ defined above is linear and that $T(v_j) = w_j$ for $j = 1, \dots, n$.

Q:Is it valid for me to figure that the existence part of this theorem means if working with basis of $V$, I can construct a linear map to whatever values I favor in $W$, while the uniqueness part means given a value $w$, which is being mapped from $V$ to $W$, and the basis of $V$, then I have but one choice for the very $T$?

Thanks for your patience for helping me, a poor beginner in linear algebra  -囧-